# how to display 1000 as 1k in laravel 7

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I'm new on La-ravel, i want to convert number value

> **from 1000 to 1k**

I have searched documentation of Laravel but i couldn't find. 
Is there any function for that?

Comment: I dont think there is any helper function out of the box. You can use [this](https://gist.github.com/RadGH/84edff0cc81e6326029c) function.

Comment: Thanks Mike Ross...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bharath-CODER put this function in your helper or create a private method inside of the controller.

```
function getAmount($input)
    {
        $input = number_format($input);
        $input_count = substr_count($input, ',');
        if ($input_count != '0') {
            if ($input_count == '1') {
                return substr($input, 0, -4) . 'k';
            } else if ($input_count == '2') {
                return substr($input, 0, -8) . 'm';
            } else if ($input_count == '3') {
                return substr($input, 0, -12) . 'b';
            } else {
                return;
            }
        } else {
            return $input;
        }
    }
```

Exampl value :
`2k`, `2m`, `2b`

Answer (score 3):

This is the best solution.

```
function intWithStyle($n)
{
  if ($n < 1000) return $n;
  $suffix = ['','k','M','G','T','P','E','Z','Y'];
  $power = floor(log($n, 1000));
  return round($n/(1000**$power),1,PHP_ROUND_HALF_EVEN).$suffix[$power];
};
```

Answer (score 0):

you may use this function/method in your controller -

```
public function convert($value)
{
    $number = $value / 1000;
    return $number . 'k';
}
```

- Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your quick response and best answer.